# How do I get the Materialize Feature Discovery Block to show up on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, materialize

I am trying to get the feature block to show up on the page when I click the open button, but it is not doing anything.  I have a sneaking suspension this has to do with the CDNs I'm importing and their position.  Or this could have something to do with the order of the relevant tap target sections in my code, I'm not really sure.  I followed the Materialize example of how to set this up verbatim, yet it seems like I can't quite get it right.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Mitchell Data Science</title>


  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../static/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
  <link href="../static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"> -->

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="static/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
  <link href="static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/init.js"></script>


</head>

<body>



  <nav class="black" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container-fluid">
      <a id="logo-container" href="index.html" class="brand-logo" style="padding-left: 30px;">Mitchell Data Science</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down" style="padding-right: 30px">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio_navigator.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="sidenav">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio_navigator.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" data-target="nav-mobile" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>




  <div id="index-banner" class="parallax-container" style="height: 350px">
    <div class="section no-pad-bot">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="header center teal-text text-darken-2" style = "font-weight: 600;">Mitchell Data Science</h1>
        <div class="row center">
          <h5 class="header col s12 dark" >Explore, Discover, Understand…</h5>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax"><img src="static/media/ds_background_1.1.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 1"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">

      <!--   Icon Section   -->


        <div class="col lg9 m9 s12">

            <div class="container">
                <br>
                <h1> Heroes of Pymoli Data Munging</h1>
                <hr><br>
            </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <div id="list-example" class="list-group" data-offset="0">
                            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-1">Abstract                 </a>
                            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-2">Wrangled Data                    </a>
                            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-3">Summary</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>




           <!-- Element Showed -->
  <div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <a id="menu" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large btn-floating" ><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
</div>


  <!-- Tap Target Structure -->
  <div class="tap-target" data-target="menu">
    <div class="tap-target-content">
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="btn" id="open">open</a>
  <a class="btn" id="close">Close</a>

  <script>
    $('#open').click(function(){
      $('.tap-target').tapTarget('open');
    });
    </script> 



                    <div class="col-9">
                        <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#list-example" data-offset="0"
                            class="scrollspy-example change-color-black">


                            <h4 id="list-item-1">Abstract</h4>
                            <p>
                                <br><br><br><br>
                                <img src="static/media/heros_fantasy.jpg"
                                    alt="Heroes of Pymoli Abstract Picture">
                                <p>

                                    In this project, I have explored a game called Heroes Of Pymoli. I will be doing some data
                                    wrangling to clean and organize my dataset, and strategically group the data to derive
                                    educated observations and assumptions.</p>

                                <br><br><br><br>
                            </p>
                            <h4 id="list-item-2">Wrangled Data</h4>
                            <p>
                                <br><br><br>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/TP_hero.PNG"
                                    alt="Total Players">
                                <br><br>
                                <hr>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/purchasing_analy_hero.PNG"
                                    alt="Purchasing Analysis">
                                <br><br>
                                <hr>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/gender_count_analy_hero.PNG"
                                    alt="Gender Analysis">
                                <br><br>
                                <hr>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/gender_purchasing_analy_hero.PNG"
                                    alt="Purchasing Analysis by Gender">
                                <br><br>
                                <hr>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/age_analy_hero.PNG"
                                    alt="Age Analysis">
                                <br><br>
                                <hr>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/most_pop_items.PNG"
                                    alt="Most Popular Items">
                                <br><br>
                                <hr>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/most_profitable_items.PNG"
                                    alt="Most Profitable Items">
                                <br><br>
                                <hr>
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/master/top_spenders.PNG"
                                    alt="Top Spenders">


                                <br><br><br><br><br>
                            </p>

                            <h4 id="list-item-3">Summary</h4>
                            <p>
                                <br><br><br><br>
                                - The 20 – 24 yo age group is the biggest age demographic for the game accounting for 44.79% of
                                the overall players. The two lowest volumes of players by age are the under 10 yo group at 2.95%
                                and the 40+ group at 2.08%.
                                <br><br>
                                - The overall total revenue from the game is $2,379.77.
                                <br><br>
                                - From the business standpoint, the 35-39 yo age group would be a goo place to focus the
                                marketing efforts. Even though their total purchase value is relatively small ($147.67) in
                                comparison to some other demographics, they spend the most on average per purchase ($3.60).
                                <br><br>
                                - Item number 178, the Oathbreaker, Last Hope of the Breaking Storm is both the most popular
                                item at 12 overall purchases, and the most profitable item at a total purchase value of $50.76.
                                <br><br>
                                - The player with the Screen Name Lisosia93 is the most prolific buyer with 5 purchases. This
                                player has spent a total of $18.96 with an average purchase amount of $3.79.
                                <br><br>
                                - Of the all the active players, the vast majority are male (84.03%). There also exists, a
                                smaller, but notable proportion of female players (14.06%).

                                <br><br><br><br><br>
                            </p>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="container">

                <h3>Project Links</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-"
                            target="_blank">Heroes Of Pymoli Data Munging</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/hgmhd7/DataViz--4---Pandas-Pandas-Pandas-Heroes-of-Pymoli-/blob/master/Heroes_Of_Pymoli_Data_Analysis_FINAL.ipynb"
                            target="_blank">Heroes Of Pymoli Kernel (Code)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hero_game_project_data.html">Data</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>










  <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
    <div class="section no-pad-bot">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row center">
          <h5 class="header col s12 light" style = "font-weight: bold">A cutting edge approch to data exploration and vizualization.</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax"><img src="static/media/ds_background_2.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 3"></div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer black">

      <div class="row">
        <h4>
          <a id="logo-container" class="brand-logo" style="padding-left: 25px;">MDS</a>
        </h4>
      </div>



    <div class="footer-copyright" style="padding-left: 25px">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        Made by <a class="brown-text text-lighten-3">  Howard G. Mitchell III</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> -->


<!-- 
  <script> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tap-target');
    var instances = M.TapTarget.init(elems, tapTarget('open'));
  });</script> -->




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: BTW the reference material I used to build this is this Youtube video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCkv49JwRUk ) and the materialize CSS website ( https://materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to initialise the Feature Discovery:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tap-target');
    var instances = M.TapTarget.init(elems);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tap-target').tapTarget();
  });
```

https://materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html#initialization

Comment: Awesome!  I initialized the tapTarget feature at the top of my HTML document and it worked for me.  Thanks for clearing that up for me!!